# PHP Wrap every 4 elements

Tags: php, xml, loops

I have this php code that wraps every 4 elements in a `div class="row"`.

My code is something like this:

```
$counter = 1;
echo '<div class="row">';
foreach($items as $item) {

  // some code here

    if($counter % 4 == 0) {
       echo '</div><div class="row">';
    }
    $counter++
}
echo '</div>';
```

This works but apparently puts an extra `div class="row"` in the end. How do I prevent this?

**UPDATE**

Ok, manage to find something. this is where i am.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/list.xml');
$count = count($xml);
$counter = 1;

if(file_exists('xml/list.xml')) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach($xml->work as $item) {
        echo $counter;
        if($counter % 4 == 0) {
           echo '</div><div class="row">';
        }
        $counter++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Dont know why but with the xml, this code puts an extra empty div. This only appears to happen when the number of xml nodes is multiple of 4.

Sample Xml

```
<list>
    <work id="1">
        <title>title here</title>
        <description>description here</description>
        <img>image name</img>
        <url>url</url>
    </work>
    <work id="2">
        <title>title here</title>
        <description>description here</description>
        <img>image name</img>
        <url>url</url>
    </work>
    <work id="3">
        <title>title here</title>
        <description>description here</description>
        <img>image name</img>
        <url>url</url>
    </work>
    <work id="4">
        <title>title here</title>
        <description>description here</description>
        <img>image name</img>
        <url>url</url>
    </work>
</list>
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: share what is current output ? and what is expected ?

Comment: use array_chunk and implode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work.

if anyone looking for the code to make php pagination with php and xml here it goes:

```
$file = 'xml/list.xml';

if(file_exists($file)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $total = count($xml);
    $counter = 0;
    $per_page = 12;
    $nPages = ceil($total/$per_page);
    $offset = ($page-1)*$per_page;
    $curr = 0;

    // xml into array
    $list = array();
    foreach($xml as $item) {
        $list[] = $item;
    }

    // displays records
    echo '<div class="work-row row">';
        foreach(array_reverse($list) as $work) {

        // show only some items per page
        $curr++;
        if($curr > $offset && $curr <= $per_page*$page) {
            // content goes here
            echo 'some code in here...';

            // every four items wrap in row
            $counter++;
            if($counter%4 == 0 && $counter < $per_page) {
                echo '</div><div class="work-row row">';
            }
        }
                    }
    echo '</div>';

    // pagination
    if($nPages > 1) {
        echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 text-right"><ul>';
        for($i=1; $i<=$nPages; $i++) {
            if($page == $i) {
                echo '<li><a href="page/'.$i.'" class="current">'.$i.'</a></li>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<li><a href="page/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
}
```

my mistake was in this line : `if($counter%4 == 0 && $counter < count($items)) {`.
changed it to `if($counter%4 == 0 && $counter < $per_page) {` and now its working great. A stupid mistake.

Tks everyone =)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the echo's outside the loop, you can add a condition avoid adding a new div on the last element like this:

```
$counter = 1;
echo '<div class="row">';
foreach($items as $item) {

  // some code here

    if($counter % 4 == 0 && $counter < count($items)) {
      echo '</div><div class="row">';
    }
    $counter++;
}
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. 
This would be my way to go if there are no performances issue.

```
<?php
$items = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
function itemsToRow($items) {
    $rows = [];
    $itemIndex = 0;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $rowIndex = (int) ($itemIndex / 4);
        $rows[$rowIndex][] = $item;
        $itemIndex++;
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

This would give you an array with the structure you need to display it.
Then to render it

```
foreach(itemsToRow($items) as $rowItems) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach($rowItems as $item) {
      echo $item;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

you can find an working example here https://eval.in/919896

What are the advantages ? You do not have to handle special cases neither inside nor outside the loop.

This reduces code complexity and enhance readability.

Comment: Fixed typos and missing `;`